# How to delete document from CouchDB using CouchPotato?

Tags: ruby, couchdb, couchpotato

I have problems finding documentation on how to delete a document from CouchDB using CouchPotato. As fare as I know I have to set the property `_deleted = true`. When I want to get documents that is not deleted, I have tried to add a condition to my class like this:

```
view :item, :key => [:userid, :date], :conditions => 'doc._deleted === nil'
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like a document can be removed with destroy_document:

    @comment = Comment.new :title => 'title';
    CouchPotato.database.save_document! @comment;
    @comment_id = @comment.id;
    CouchPotato.database.destroy_document @comment;

Answer (score 3):

`CouchPotato.database.destroy <my_model_instance>`

Comment: would be great to have that in the gitrepo README - I'll try to send a PR :)